# Network in UI thread in an android device(android 3.0 or newer)

Tags: android, file, networking, jsoup

I have to parse a website html code and show some info in my app
So I tried JSoup for getting result
It works great on the emulator but in a real device it will crashes; here is the log :

```
05-25 21:42:20.935: D/AndroidRuntime(32230): Shutting down VM  
05-25 21:42:20.935: W/dalvikvm(32230): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401b9760)  
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abbasizadeh.Currency/com.abbasizadeh.Currency.CurrencyUpdatableActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:404)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:391)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:157)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:146)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at com.abbasizadeh.Currency.CurrencyUpdater.updateInfo(CurrencyUpdater.java:35)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at com.abbasizadeh.Currency.CurrencyUpdatableActivity.onCreate(CurrencyUpdatableActivity.java:20)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230):    ... 11 more
```

in `CurrencyUpdatableActivity.java:20` I call `CurrencyUpdater.java:35` and
`CurrencyUpdater.java:35` is this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

thank you for your help in this strange issue

Edit: I added the android version problem to my title for better search for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android 3.0 and newer, you're banned from touching the network or file IO on the UI thread.  This is a good thing since it forces you to not interrupt the user interface for operations that may take a long time. Look at this line in your log:

```
05-25 21:42:20.940: E/AndroidRuntime(32230): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You've already figured out where the exception is thrown, now you need to put that code in the doInBackground() method of an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Thaank you so much. You said the exact problem : it's because of the android version.